# MultiValueDictKeyError when sending POST requests

Tags: python, django

I'm making an expense tracker web app, but when I want to send POST requests, it fails.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Token(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=48)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}_token".format(self.user)

class Expense(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} -{}".format(self.date, self.amount)

class Income(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} +{}".format(self.date, self.amount)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from json import JSONEncoder
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from web.models import User, Token, Expense, Income
from datetime import datetime

@csrf_exempt
def submit_expense(request):
    this_token = request.POST['token']
    this_user = User.objects.filter(token__token = this_token).get()
    now = datetime.now()
    Expense.objects.create(
                           user = this_user, amount=request.POST['amount'], text=request.POST['text'], date=now
                           )

    return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'ok',
        }, encoder=JSONEncoder)
```

I assume this way of sending POST requests are expired, but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: well apparently the `token`, `amount`, etc. is missing. How did you make the HTTP request?

Comment: I'm making POST requests with POSTMAN. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Please add (1) the view that creates the page where the post request is coming from, and (2), the html template of that page.  The error means that `request.POST` does not have a key called `'token'`, so `request.POST['token']` raises the `MultiValueDictKeyError`.